# How to assign IAM Role for ECS Task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs

ECS Tasks can be assigned IAM Roles to make it possible to communicate with AWS APIs without having to pass user credentials to the Task. 
This works for both AWS CLI and SDK. There is quite good documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) but I couldn't find a proper example that covers all the details, I'll create a self-answer question to spare the pain for others.

Answer (score 2):

I created a [Git repo with the full example](https://github.com/adam-sandor/ecs-task-role). The important bits are:

- Creating an IAM Role Definition with an AssumeRolePolicyDocument.
- Assigning the IAM Role to the Task.
- Using the AWS JS SDK.

  ```
  IAMRole:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub role-task-${AWS::StackName} # Doesn't matter too much but let's make it nice anyway
      Path: / # No idea about this one but / seems to work
      # This is the funky stuff.. don't try to understand just copy-paste. Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_IAM_role.html
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: |
          {
              "Statement": [{
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Principal": { "Service": [ "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com" ]},
                  "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
              }]
          }
      Policies:
          - PolicyName: !Sub ecs-task-${AWS::StackName}
            # You can add any actions here you want your container to be allowed to execute.
            PolicyDocument:
              {
                  "Version": "2012-10-17",
                  "Statement": [{
                          "Effect": "Allow",
                          "Action": [
                              "cloudwatch:PutMetricData" # more actions if needed
                          ],
                          "Resource": "*"
                  }]
              }
  ```

The initialisation of the AWS SDK. The AWS SDK will automatically detect that the container has access to the Role credentials and initialise itself. You don't have to do any initialisation, besides creating the API objects.

```
 var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

 var cw = new AWS.CloudWatch();
 var s3 = new AWS.S3();
```

Comment: You should not need to manually fetch the credentials or initialize the SDK with those credentials; all the SDKs (after the feature was introduced) should do this automatically.  Check [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html#task-iam-roles-minimum-sdk) for minimum SDK versions.

Comment: How would the init code look like then? Just `new AWS.Config()` ?
I was trying to get it working without manually fetching the credentials but I didn't manage.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the SDK for JavaScript, but it does look like the default credential provider chain is correct: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/1941f9b615cd123baee96898b9e3eb217700d491/lib/node_loader.js#L36-L50

Comment: So the solution is that you shouldn't mess around with AWS.Config at all. Can you check if it's correct now @SamuelKarp?